# Unable to start apache2.2 gave me No such file or directory

Tags: php, apache, apache2

I know this is my fault. What I did was upgrade my php 5.3 to the latest php5.5. But due to some important reason I need to roll back to my previous php version which is 5.3.10. Upgrading to the latest php5 gave me no sweat but when I roll back it gave me this error:

```
$ sudo service apache2 start
 * Starting web server apache2                                                           apache2: Syntax error on line 210 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/access_compat.load: 
Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_access_compat.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_access_compat.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Please help anyone.

Comment: Try asking this question on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) instead of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Comment line 2 in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/access_compat.load and all other include problems, 3 for me

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when downgraded apache from 2.4 to 2.2, so i had to disable the modules there enabled in the 2.4 installation.

```
a2dismod <module-name>
```